# Change the string to tabular format using Athena query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I have this JSON file

```
{"Item":{"author":{"S":"John"},"title":{"S":"Page A"},"mytext":{"S":"This is sample text"}}}
{"Item":{"author":{"S":"Ram"},"title":{"S":"Page B"},"mytext":{"S":"Another book text"}}}
```

I created a table in Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE financials_raw_json (
  Item string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://lambdaoks/AWSDynamoDB/016/data/'
```

I get the results as string. This is expected and correct.

But is it possible to get tabular results? For e.g.

```
author  title   mytext
John    Page A  This is sample text
Ram Page B  Another book text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to explode a string instead of creating the table as it exists in DynamoDB?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS financials_raw_json (
  Item struct <author:struct<S:string>,
               title:struct<S:string>,
               myText:struct<S:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION LOCATION 's3://lambdaoks/AWSDynamoDB/016/data/'
```

If you don't want to create the table manually you could run a Glue crawler on it with a JSON classifier which will provide you with the same output automatically.

Comment: The query to select data is: SELECT Item.author.s, Item.title.s, Item.mytext.s FROM tbl
Refernece: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-and-visualize-nested-json-data-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/